# What is DataclassOwnersManager?

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8563977

A strange process is running on an un-logged-in user and taking up tons of resources.  It's called "DataclassOwnersManager."

I was able to force quit the process, but am still not comfortable with it.

Any idea what this process was?